# 2003 tiburon alarm disengage

Tags: hyundai, alarm, tiburon

Car will not start on key. I can jump start and cross the starter.
Seems the burglar alarm is set but no horn. I have never used alarm and
seldom or never remove the key. Power to the switch but not to starter relay.
No power going thru ignition lock on clutch. I do not have the keyless fob.
Is there anyway of unlocking the alarm? Is it in the ECU? Tried everything,
about to give up and install a bypass jumper.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest if it will start off of jumping the starter your alarm isn't what's at issue. The alarm would cause the ignition through the ECU not to work, so wouldn't fire at all whether it's key or jumped or what have you. The alarm systems are usually a bit smarter than that. I'd suggest this is some other problem like the ignition switch itself or some kind of relay not kicking in.

Comment: Generally the switch on the clutch passes ground to the starter relay. The ignition switch will power the starter relay coil? Or does the ignition switch pass power and you're not seeing power at the relay coil? Have you load tested the wiring?

Comment: I gave up, and installed a push button. Spent enough time on an older cheap car. The push button cost 5$. Perhaps it was not the alarm, I just could not find any other reason.